# What code can I use to create Excel macros for keyboard shortcuts with formatting toggles?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I'm trying to write macros that will allow me to use a keyboard shortcut to quickly cycle through various options. Example, if I want to change the font colors in the "Start" column below, pressing the shortcut CTRL + SHIFT + C consecutively would change the fonts to black, then to blue, then to green, then to red, and cycle back to black (and continue to cycle each time I used the shortcut). I have correct code for that, but can't figure out the others. Thank you in advance for any help.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.
Example for font colors:
[image]

Following the same logic, I'd like to use different shortcuts for the following formatting toggles.
Toggle capabilities for each type of formatting:
[image]

Here is the code that works for font color toggling:

```
Sub ToggleFontColor()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim allBlack As Boolean
    allBlack = True

    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell.Font.Color <> vbBlack Then
            allBlack = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    If allBlack Then
        Selection.Font.Color = vbBlue
    Else
        For Each cell In Selection
            Select Case cell.Font.Color
                Case vbBlue
                    cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                Case RGB(0, 176, 80)
                    cell.Font.Color = vbRed
                Case Else
                    cell.Font.Color = vbBlack
            End Select
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```